# Nginx secure proxy to external site

Tags: nginx

We have a simple problem which I'm hoping NGINX can solve, as it is my preferred tool for things like this.

We have a secure internal network which has several POS machines which need to communicate to an externally hosted site, but they cannot do it directly due to our clients security not wanting open access.

I'm trying to figure out a NGINX config that can do the following:

Receive requests on the internal network for say http://xxxx/yyyy and then reverse proxy them to https://externalsite/yyyy

Without SSL I seem to be able to achieve something, but my problem is doing this with SSL.
I don't care that the internal communication is secured, but require that the proxy to external comms be secured.

I'm not even sure a reverse proxy is the best solution for this, but an getting no-where discovering any other options.

**Current Config**

```
worker_processes  5;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

events {
  worker_connections  4096;
}

http {
  include    proxy.conf;
  index    index.html index.htm index.php;

  log_format   main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '
    '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  sendfile     on;
  tcp_nopush   on;
  server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;

  server {
    listen       80;

    location / {
      proxy_pass   http://example.com/xxx/;
      proxy_set_header Host example.com;
    }
  }
}
```

**Proxy.conf**

```
proxy_redirect          off;
proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
client_max_body_size    10m;
client_body_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_connect_timeout   90;
proxy_send_timeout      90;
proxy_read_timeout      90;
proxy_buffers           32 4k;
```

Any help or suggestions are much appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: please post the nginx config that works without SSL

Comment: I've edited my post to include my current config